# Can an object infer an overridden field's type from a trait?

Tags: scala

I am generating some test data as follows:

```
trait Template {
  val field1: Map[List[String], Map[Int, List[Boolean]]] //the type is for illustration. Think of it as a 'monstrous type definition'
  val field2: Map[List[Int], Map[Double, List[Option[String]]]]
}

object Fixture extends Template {
  override val field1 = Map()
  override val field2 = Map() 
}
```

This fails with the message `value field1 has incompatible type`, ditto for `field2`?

I can fix it by providing types in `Fixture` explicitly, but I am trying to avoid this because if I change a type inside the trait I will need to propagate it to every fixture object.

Can my `object Fixture` infer the types for `field1` and `field2` from `trait Template`.

Comment: [type aliases FTW](http://scalafiddle.net/console/ddf88ea64eaed0f3de5531ac964a0a1a)

Comment: That doesn't solve his issue. He wants to be able to change the types and reuse the `trait`. You can't do this however because changing a type, specifically to a type that isn't co/contravariant, is tantamount to changing it from a `Map` to a `Fruit` its a different type altogether.

Comment: @nsfyn55 huh? If I have to change `type Monster1 = Map[... [Boolean]]` to `type Monster1 = Map[... [Int]]`, I don't need to go over all implementers and replace Boolean with Int in signatures, given that Monster1 was used in them.

Comment: @om-nom-nom ah never mind I was reading it backwards. Alias away!

Comment: This is a possible solution, thanks. I have a lot of those fields though (in different templates), and template definition is really the only place I'm using these types. Still though, this seems to be obvious, why compiler does not pick it up?

Comment: But I explicitly override `field1` in `Fixture`, so it can infer `Map[...]` type. Now, I assign to it a `Map()`, without generic args, which should work, no?

Comment: According to this article(http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4660) its a limitation of the Hindley Milner type system that limits you to local type inference.

Comment: It seems to be invariant type parameters (the first parameter of Map) that object to this overriding. They need more information to be inferred than co/contra-variance parameters due to the fact that they need to be inferred exactly, i.e. can't just go for `Nothing` or `Any` and then get assigned. This [fiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console/a57d48399922b03419153a9760c5ce53) shows what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the compiler isn't smart enough to infer the right type for a `val`, but it will for a `def`. You can get around the problem by putting the initialization code into a def.

```
trait Template {
  val field1 = field1Init
  def field1Init: Map[List[String], Map[Int, List[Boolean]]]
  val field2 = field2Init
  def field2Init: Map[List[Int], Map[Double, List[Option[String]]]]
}

object Fixture extends Template {
  override def field1Init = Map()
  override def field2Init = Map() 
}
```